# Decoding a WAV File Header

Tags: hex, wav

I'm trying to understand the header of a WAV file. I've opened an example file and got this:

```
5249 4646 e857 1400 5741 5645 666d 7420
1000 0000 0100 0200 44ac 0000 10b1 0200
0400 1000
```

I've been reading [this data representation tutorial](http://www.itk.ilstu.edu/faculty/javila/DataTypes/soundWav.htm#1).

I understand that `52` is one byte and represents the ASCII letter `R`. I understand up to the `1000 0000`. Why does that represent decimal 16? The tutorial says that the value at that position is always `0x10`. How does `1000 0000` equate to `0x10`.

Also, when reading the file, will a program know whether to expect a number or ASCII? Presumably it'll check against a value that is already in HEX?

Thanks

Comment: Your tutorial has a link explaining "Little-Endian" format. Read it. The bytes are in this order: 0x10 0x00 0x00 0x00. The least significant byte is first, so the whole number is 0x00000010. (Decomposing it into `1000` and `0000` is not helpful at all.)

Comment: That'd be how Sublime formatted, hence my confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Hope this helps a little, I'm going to mention everything just to clear:

**Something to use for hex in general:** I use a hex editor, `dhex`, which you should be able to `apt-get`, `yum`, or `brew` install on your favorite unix like machine. I'll be using [this site](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/) as the source for most of this material:

As you alluded to, the first 4 bytes of hex represent ASCII characters. In this case, those characters area always:

```
52 49 46 46 - RIFF
```

The next 4 bytes represent the chunk size, which is little endian. In your case it is:

```
e8 57 14 00 - 1333224
```

The next 8 bytes represent ASCII characters again. In your case:

```
57 41 56 45 - WAVE
66 6d 74 20 - fmt.
```

The next 4 represent the chunk size, which is little endian:

```
10 00 00 00 - 268435456
```

This chuck does not represent decimal 16, it represents decimal 268435456 in 16bits (4 bytes with 1 bytes being 4 bits). for reasons as to "why" the chunks are 16bits, you can read more of on this [Intro to Audio Programing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dawate/2009/06/23/intro-to-audio-programming-part-2-demystifying-the-wav-format/). This describes that the chunks in the data section will be 16bit.

`01 00` represents the audio format (little endian), 1 stands for PCI in this case.  `02 00` represents the number of channels, which is 2 in your case.

The next 4 bytes represent the sample rate (little endian), or

> The number of samples ( frames) that exist for each second of data. This field is represented in Hz. - taken from [here](http://www.topherlee.com/software/pcm-tut-wavformat.html).

```
44 ac 00 00 - 44100
```

The next 4 bytes represent the byte rate(little endian):

```
10 b1 02 00 - 1049265
```

The next 2 bytes represent the block align:

> This is the number of bytes in a frame (little endian). This is calculated by multiplying the number of channels by the number of bytes (not bits) in a sample. You can find more detailed calculations [here](http://www.topherlee.com/software/pcm-tut-wavformat.html)

```
04 00 - 4
```

Next are your 2 bytes that represent bits per sample(little endian), in your case it is 16

```
10 00 - 16
```

**The Data Section:**

You do not currently have a data section in your `.wav` file, in order to start the data section you first write the ASCII values for `data` like so (big endian):

```
64 61 74 61 - data
```

After this you need 4 bytes representing your chunk 2 size and you should be good to go. In terms of testing, I would recommend reading [this guide](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/) if you have not already. I would also recommenced reading this post about how to build raw wav files [Digital Audio - Creating a WAV (RIFF) file](http://www.topherlee.com/software/pcm-tut-wavformat.html) , this should also help in understanding how to "decode" them.

Comment: This should be first result when people search WAV programming on Google. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the chunkSize of the **fmt** chunk is not supposed to be 16? In other places I have checked online I haven't seen anywhere that you say about it being 268435456. Also the rest of the fmt chunk seems to be 16 bytes...