# Unable to play wav files from play scala application

Tags: java, scala, audio, playframework

WAV file is valid and can play using VLC. However, play/scala application is not able to play and throws this exception:

```
Caused by: com.sun.media.sound.RIFFInvalidDataException: Chunk size too big
```

Code:

```
def play() = {
  val in = new FileInputStream("/Users/xxx/hello_world.wav");
  val audioStream = new AudioStream(in);
  AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
}
```

Apparently this happens when size is not included in the wav file but not sure. Any way I can get around this exception?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [JDK bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8132782) the issue is that the file is larger than 2 gigabytes:

> Trying to read Wav-Files greater than 2 GiB results in a
>
> RIFFInvalidDataException("Chunk size too big")
>
> …
>
> As a WAVE-File can be up to 4 GiB in size it should be possible to work with files greater than the current possible 2 GiB.

That bug report says that it was fixed in JDK 9. Try out the latest JDK and see if that fixes it.

You can use Play Framework with Java 9 but there are some warts still. The main thing is that you'll need to provide the following command line option when running *sbt*.

```
SBT_OPTS="--add-modules java.xml.bind" sbt
```

Java 9 support for Play is a work in progress. See this issue for discussion and updates: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/7879

Comment: file I used is about 180K

Comment: According to [the source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/client/jdk/rev/5ef5a53e79b8#l1.45) the error is caused if a field in the file is greater than `Integer.Max_VALUE`. Perhaps it's a corrupted file?

Comment: I can play the file successfully in VNC

Comment: Can you open the file in a hex editor and get the chunk size? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37741002/49630) - you're looking at bytes 5-8 (starting at 1).