# Header missing error while playing MP3/WAV files recorded using MediaRecorder on ESP32 using ESP32-audioI2S library

Tags: javascript, audio, esp32, web-mediarecorder, i2s

I am trying to record a .mp3 and a .wav using [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) Javascript library on a webpage and play it on ESP32 using [ESP32-audioI2S](https://github.com/schreibfaul1/ESP32-audioI2S) library. I am able to play the recorded MP3 and WAV file on PC with audacity player/Windows player. But same MP3/WAV is not being played by ESP32 with the library. I get **RIFF header missing** for WAV file and **header missing** for MP3 file.  I am attaching the code used for recording using MediaRecorder, the code used for playing the recorded and downloaded audio files and the error messages I get. Is there anything wrong with the code used for recording audio? Or is there anything I am missing in the library? Thanks in advance for your help.

Board used: ESP32 Dev Module

UDA1334A (Adafruit I2S Stereo Decoder Breakout Board) used for playing audio.

CODE:

1. for playing audio (fairly straightforward)

```
    #include <Audio.h>
    #include <WiFi.h>
    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <SD.h>
    #include <FS.h>
    #define I2S_DOUT      25  // connect to DAC pin DIN
    #define I2S_BCLK      27  // connect to DAC pin BCK
    #define I2S_LRC       26  // connect to DAC pin LCK
    #define SD_CS 5
    Audio audio;
    
    void setup() {
        Serial.begin(115200);
        // initializing sd card
      if (!SD.begin(SD_CS)) {
        Serial.println("Card Mount Failed");
        return;
      }
      uint8_t cardType = SD.cardType();
      if (cardType == CARD_NONE) {
        Serial.println("No SD card attached");
        return;
      }
        audio.setPinout(I2S_BCLK, I2S_LRC, I2S_DOUT);
        audio.setVolume(21);
        //audio.connecttoFS(SD, "test16k.wav"); // 16khz sample rate; playing fine; recorded in audacity
        //audio.connecttoFS(SD, "teststd.mp3"); // 16khz sample rate; playing fine; recorded in audacity
        audio.connecttoFS(SD, "sampleMp3.mp3"); // recorded using mediaRecorder - not working
        //audio.connecttoFS(SD, "sampleWav.wav"); // recorded using mediaRecorder - not working
    }
    
    void loop() {
        audio.loop();
    }
    
    void audio_info(const char *info){
        Serial.print("info        "); Serial.println(info);
    }
```

2. For recording - js, html and css files disclosed (probably just the js file will do)

```js
// index.js file

const mediaSelector = document.getElementById("media");

const webCamContainer =
    document.getElementById("web-cam-container");

let selectedMedia = null;

// This array stores the recorded media data
let chunks = [];

// Handler function to handle the "change" event
// when the user selects some option
mediaSelector.addEventListener("change", (e) => {

    // Takes the current value of the mediaSeletor
    selectedMedia = e.target.value;

    document.getElementById(
        `${selectedMedia}-recorder`)
        .style.display = "block";

    document.getElementById(
        `${otherRecorderContainer(
            selectedMedia)}-recorder`)
        .style.display = "none";
});

function otherRecorderContainer(
    selectedMedia) {

    return selectedMedia === "vid" ?
        "aud" : "vid";
}

// This constraints object tells
// the browser to include only
// the audio Media Track
const audioMediaConstraints = {
    audio: true,
    video: false,
};

// This constraints object tells
// the browser to include
// both the audio and video
// Media Tracks
const videoMediaConstraints = {

    // or you can set audio to
    // false to record
    // only video
    audio: true,
    video: true,
};

// When the user clicks the "Start
// Recording" button this function
// gets invoked
function startRecording(
    thisButton, otherButton) {
    
    // Access the camera and microphone
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
        selectedMedia === "vid" ?
            videoMediaConstraints :
            audioMediaConstraints)
        .then((mediaStream) => {


            // Create a new MediaRecorder instance
            
            const mediaRecorder =
                // new MediaRecorder(mediaStream,options);
                new MediaRecorder(mediaStream);
            //Make the mediaStream global
            window.mediaStream = mediaStream;
            //Make the mediaRecorder global
            window.mediaRecorder = mediaRecorder;

            mediaRecorder.start();

            // Whenever (here when the recorder
            // stops recording) data is available
            // the MediaRecorder emits a "dataavailable"
            // event with the recorded media data.
            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {

                // Push the recorded media data to
                // the chunks array
                chunks.push(e.data);
            };

            // When the MediaRecorder stops
            // recording, it emits "stop"
            // event
            mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {

                /* A Blob is a File like object.
                In fact, the File interface is
                based on Blob. File inherits the
                Blob interface and expands it to
                support the files on the user's
                systemThe Blob constructor takes
                the chunk of media data as the
                first parameter and constructs
                a Blob of the type given as the
                second parameter*/
                const blob = new Blob(
                    chunks, {
                    type: selectedMedia === "vid" ?
                        "video/mp4" : "audio/mp3"  // audio/wav for wav file
                });
                chunks = [];

                // Create a video or audio element
                // that stores the recorded media
                const recordedMedia = document.createElement(
                    selectedMedia === "vid" ? "video" : "audio");
                recordedMedia.controls = true;

                // You can not directly set the blob as
                // the source of the video or audio element
                // Instead, you need to create a URL for blob
                // using URL.createObjectURL() method.
                const recordedMediaURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                // Now you can use the created URL as the
                // source of the video or audio element
                recordedMedia.src = recordedMediaURL;

                // Create a download button that lets the
                // user download the recorded media
                const downloadButton = document.createElement("a");

                // Set the download attribute to true so that
                // when the user clicks the link the recorded
                // media is automatically gets downloaded.
                downloadButton.download = "Recorded-Media";

                downloadButton.href = recordedMediaURL;
                downloadButton.innerText = "Download it!";

                downloadButton.onclick = () => {

                    /* After download revoke the created URL
                    using URL.revokeObjectURL() method to
                    avoid possible memory leak. Though,
                    the browser automatically revokes the
                    created URL when the document is unloaded,
                    but still it is good to revoke the created
                    URLs */
                    URL.revokeObjectURL(recordedMedia);
                };

                document.getElementById(
                    `${selectedMedia}-recorder`).append(
                        recordedMedia, downloadButton);
            };

            if (selectedMedia === "vid") {

                // Remember to use the srcObject
                // attribute since the src attribute
                // doesn't support media stream as a value
                webCamContainer.srcObject = mediaStream;
            }

            document.getElementById(
                `${selectedMedia}-record-status`)
                .innerText = "Recording";

            thisButton.disabled = true;
            otherButton.disabled = false;
        });
}


function stopRecording(thisButton, otherButton) {

    // Stop the recording
    window.mediaRecorder.stop();

    // Stop all the tracks in the
    // received media stream
    window.mediaStream.getTracks()
        .forEach((track) => {
            track.stop();
        });

    document.getElementById(
        `${selectedMedia}-record-status`)
        .innerText = "Recording done!";
    thisButton.disabled = true;
    otherButton.disabled = false;
}
```

```css
//index.css file (just in case you need it)

body {
    text-align: center;
    color: green;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
  
.display-none {
    display: none;
}
  
.recording {
    color: red;
    background-color: rgb(241 211 211);
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 6px auto;
    width: fit-content;
}
  
video {
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px auto;
    width: 420px;
    height: 240px;
}
  
audio {
    display: block;
    margin: 6px auto;
}
  
a {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
//index.html file (just in case you need it)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>Video & Audio Recorder</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1> Video & Audio Recorder </h1>
    <label for="media">
        Select what you want to record:
    </label>

    <select id="media">
        <option value="choose-an-option">
            Choose an option
        </option>
        <option value="vid">Video</option>
        <option value="aud">Audio</option>
    </select>

    <div class="display-none" id="vid-recorder">
        <h3>Record Video </h3>
        <video autoplay id="web-cam-container" style="background-color: black;">
            Your browser doesn't support
            the video tag
        </video>

        <div class="recording" id="vid-record-status">
            Click the "Start video Recording"
            button to start recording
        </div>

        <!-- This button will start the video recording -->
        <button type="button" id="start-vid-recording" onclick="startRecording(this,
            document.getElementById('stop-vid-recording'))">
            Start video recording
        </button>

        <!-- This button will stop the video recording -->
        <button type="button" id="stop-vid-recording" disabled onclick="stopRecording(this,
            document.getElementById('start-vid-recording'))">
            Stop video recording
        </button>

        <!--The video element will be created using
            JavaScript and contains recorded video-->
        <!-- <video id="recorded-video" controls>
            Your browser doesn't support the video tag
        </video> -->

        <!-- The below link will let the
            users download the recorded video -->
        <!-- <a href="" > Download it! </a> -->
    </div>

    <div class="display-none" id="aud-recorder">
        <h3> Record Audio</h3>

        <div class="recording" id="aud-record-status">
            Click the "Start Recording"
            button to start recording
        </div>

        <button type="button" id="start-aud-recording" onclick="startRecording(this,
            document.getElementById('stop-aud-recording'))">
            Start recording
        </button>

        <button type="button" id="stop-aud-recording" disabled onclick="stopRecording(this,
            document.getElementById('start-aud-recording'))">
            Stop recording
        </button>

        <!-- The audio element will contain the
            recorded audio and will be created
            using Javascript -->
        <!-- <audio id="recorded-audio"
            controls></audio> -->

        <!-- The below link will let the users
            download the recorded audio -->
        <!-- <a href="" > Download it! </a> -->
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

ERROR MESSAGES:

wav file:

```
12:25:03.750 -> info PSRAM not found, inputBufferSize: 6399 bytes
12:25:03.750 -> info buffers freed, free Heap: 286876 bytes
12:25:03.750 -> info Reading file: "/sampleWav.wav"
12:25:03.797 -> info stream ready
12:25:03.797 -> info file has no RIFF tag
12:25:03.797 -> info syncword found at pos 0
12:25:03.797 -> Guru Meditation Error: Core 1 panic'ed (IntegerDivideByZero). Exception was unhandled.
12:25:03.797 -> Core 1 register dump:
12:25:03.797 -> PC : 0x400d7423 PS : 0x00060530 A0 : 0x800d78ec A1 : 0x3ffb1f00
12:25:03.797 -> A2 : 0x3ffbff28 A3 : 0x3ffc2328 A4 : 0x00000640 A5 : 0x3ffc2428
12:25:03.844 -> A6 : 0x3ffc0328 A7 : 0xff000000 A8 : 0x00000000 A9 : 0x3ffb1ee0
12:25:03.844 -> A10 : 0x3ffc03f6 A11 : 0x3ffb2068 A12 : 0x00000640 A13 : 0x00000000
12:25:03.844 -> A14 : 0x3ffc0328 A15 : 0x3ffb889c SAR : 0x0000001b EXCCAUSE: 0x00000006
12:25:03.844 -> EXCVADDR: 0x00000000 LBEG : 0x400014fd LEND : 0x4000150d LCOUNT : 0xffffffff
12:25:03.844 ->
12:25:03.844 -> ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000
12:25:03.844 ->
12:25:03.844 -> Backtrace: 0x400d7423:0x3ffb1f00 0x400d78e9:0x3ffb1f40 0x400da6e1:0x3ffb1f70 0x400d1846:0x3ffb1f90 0x400ee7b1:0x3ffb1fb0 0x400865de:0x3ffb1fd0
12:25:03.892 ->
12:25:03.892 -> Rebooting...
12:25:04.141 -> info PSRAM not found, inputBufferSize: 6399 bytes
12:25:04.141 -> info buffers freed, free Heap: 286876 bytes
12:25:04.141 -> info Reading file: "/sampleWav.wav"
12:25:04.188 -> info stream ready
12:25:04.188 -> info file has no RIFF tag
12:25:04.188 -> info syncword found at pos 0
12:25:04.188 -> Guru Meditation Error: Core 1 panic'ed (IntegerDivideByZero). Exception was unhandled.
12:25:04.188 -> Core 1 register dump:
12:25:04.188 -> PC : 0x400d7423 PS : 0x00060530 A0 : 0x800d78ec A1 : 0x3ffb1f00
12:25:04.235 -> A2 : 0x3ffbff28 A3 : 0x3ffc2328 A4 : 0x00000640 A5 : 0x3ffc2428
12:25:04.235 -> A6 : 0x3ffc0328 A7 : 0xff000000 A8 : 0x00000000 A9 : 0x3ffb1ee0
12:25:04.235 -> A10 : 0x3ffc03f6 A11 : 0x3ffb2068 A12 : 0x00000640 A13 : 0x00000000
12:25:04.235 -> A14 : 0x3ffc0328 A15 : 0x3ffb889c SAR : 0x0000001b EXCCAUSE: 0x00000006
12:25:04.235 -> EXCVADDR: 0x00000000 LBEG : 0x400014fd LEND : 0x4000150d LCOUNT : 0xffffffff
12:25:04.235 ->
12:25:04.235 -> ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000
```

mp3 file:

```
12:51:19.860 -> info PSRAM not found, inputBufferSize: 6399 bytes
12:51:19.860 -> info buffers freed, free Heap: 286876 bytes
12:51:19.860 -> info Reading file: "/sampleMp3.mp3"
12:51:19.860 -> info MP3Decoder has been initialized, free Heap: 262912 bytes
12:51:19.907 -> info stream ready
12:51:19.907 -> info Content-Length: 85414
12:51:19.907 -> info file has no mp3 tag, skip metadata
12:51:19.907 -> info Audio-Length: 85414
12:51:19.907 -> info syncword found at pos 41
12:51:19.907 -> info syncword found at pos 0
12:51:19.907 -> info MP3 decode error -6 : INVALID_FRAMEHEADER
12:51:19.907 -> info syncword found at pos 0
12:51:19.907 -> info MP3 decode error -6 : INVALID_FRAMEHEADER
12:51:19.907 -> info syncword found at pos 0
12:51:19.969 -> info MP3 decode error -6 : INVALID_FRAMEHEADER
12:51:19.969 -> info syncword found at pos 104
12:51:19.969 -> info syncword found at pos 0
12:51:19.969 -> info MP3 decode error -6 : INVALID_FRAMEHEADER
12:51:19.969 -> info syncword found at pos 0
12:51:19.969 -> info MP3 decode error -6 : INVALID_FRAMEHEADER
12:51:19.969 -> info syncword found at pos 0
12:51:19.969 -> info MP3 decode error -6 : INVALID_FRAMEHEADER
12:51:19.969 -> info syncword found at pos 15
12:51:19.969 -> info syncword found at pos 0
12:51:19.969 -> info MP3 decode error -6 : INVALID_FRAMEHEADER
12:51:19.969 -> info syncword not found
12:51:19.969 -> info syncword found at pos 1405
12:51:19.969 -> info syncword not found 10 times
12:51:19.969 -> info MP3 decode error -6 : INVALID_FRAMEHEADER
12:51:19.969 -> info syncword found at pos 1145
12:51:19.969 -> info syncword found at pos 0
12:51:19.969 -> info MP3 decode error -6 : INVALID_FRAMEHEADER
12:51:20.001 -> info syncword not found
12:51:20.001 -> info syncword found at pos 1591
12:51:20.001 -> info syncword not found 21 times
12:51:20.001 -> info MP3 decode error -9 : INVALID_HUFFCODES
12:51:20.001 -> info syncword not found
12:51:20.047 -> info syncword found at pos 1411
12:51:20.047 -> info syncword not found 17 times
12:51:20.047 -> info MP3 decode error -6 : INVALID_FRAMEHEADER
12:51:20.047 -> info syncword not found
12:51:20.047 -> info syncword found at pos 1495
12:51:20.095 -> info syncword not found 31 times
12:51:20.095 -> info MP3 decode error -6 : INVALID_FRAMEHEADER
12:51:20.095 -> info syncword found at pos 178
12:51:20.095 -> info syncword found at pos 0
12:51:20.095 -> info MP3 decode error -6 : INVALID_FRAMEHEADER
12:51:20.095 -> info syncword not found
12:51:20.141 -> info syncword found at pos 1460
12:51:20.141 -> info syncword not found 49 times
12:51:20.141 -> E (326) I2S: clkmdiv is too large

12:51:20.141 ->
12:51:20.141 -> info Channels: 0
12:51:20.141 -> info SampleRate: 0
12:51:20.141 -> info BitsPerSample: 16
12:51:20.141 -> info BitRate: N/A
12:51:20.141 -> Guru Meditation Error: Core 1 panic'ed (IntegerDivideByZero). Exception was unhandled.
12:51:20.141 -> Core 1 register dump:
12:51:20.141 -> PC : 0x400d7603 PS : 0x00060d30 A0 : 0x800d78ec A1 : 0x3ffb1f00
12:51:20.188 -> A2 : 0x3ffbff28 A3 : 0x3ffc2328 A4 : 0x000000a8 A5 : 0x00000000
12:51:20.188 -> A6 : 0x3ffc0328 A7 : 0x3b245260 A8 : 0x800d7600 A9 : 0x3ffb1ee0
12:51:20.188 -> A10 : 0x00000000 A11 : 0x3ffc0328 A12 : 0x400d184c A13 : 0x00000000
12:51:20.188 -> A14 : 0x3ffc0328 A15 : 0x00000000 SAR : 0x00000004 EXCCAUSE: 0x00000006
12:51:20.188 -> EXCVADDR: 0x00000000 LBEG : 0x400014fd LEND : 0x4000150d LCOUNT : 0xffffffff
12:51:20.188 ->
12:51:20.188 -> ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000
12:51:20.188 ->
12:51:20.188 -> Backtrace: 0x400d7603:0x3ffb1f00 0x400d78e9:0x3ffb1f40 0x400da6e1:0x3ffb1f70 0x400d1846:0x3ffb1f90 0x400ee7b1:0x3ffb1fb0 0x400865de:0x3ffb1fd0
12:51:20.235 ->
12:51:20.235 -> Rebooting...
```

Comment: Setting a mime type doesn't magically convert the data into the desired format.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm just a beginner and I don't know what to make of your reply. What do you suggest that I do? As I mentioned before, the recorded audio is playing everywhere else except on ESP32 using the library.

Comment: I can't get to play those recordings with anything. And the browser probably doesn't even support recording in mp3 format. Also "audio/mp3" isn't mp3's mime type.

Comment: I checked the wav file's metadata using [link] (https://www.metadata2go.com/). I see the header is missing and rightly so. The answer provided here [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992898/decoding-a-wav-file-header) helped me understand. Now to rephrase my question, How to programatically add header to a wav file using javascript? Or how to convert a webm file to a valid wav file using javascript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web Audio API - record to MP3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881703/web-audio-api-record-to-mp3)

Comment: @gre_gor I used recorderjs library, it solved the problem. It records directly in wav format. Now I'll use lamejs to encode it to mp3. Guess that should work? Thankyou for your time!